# Python: Unpack tuple in loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am haunted by a seemingly benign programming error, but unfortunately I do not understand the reason.

I iteratively construct a dictionary. Each element contains a list of tuples. The responsible code looks like that:

```
# ...
for string, integer in another_dict[document_name]:
        new_dict[document_name].append((integer * other_integers[string][1], other_integers[string][0]))
```

Later on I want to read `new_dict`.

```
sorted_list = sorted(new_dict[document_name], key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for t1, t2 in sorted_list:
    file_content += str(t1) + ":" + str(t2) + "|"
```

This works for a while, but eventually results in a *'float' object has no attribute '__getitem* error. I am aware of the meaning: There must be an item in sorted_list that cannot be unpaced in t1 and t2. Bizarrely I could ensure that each item in sorted_list is a tuple:

```
for item in sorted_list:
     if not isinstance(item, tuple):
           print "culprit was found: " + item # was never printed
```

I even printed my `sorted_list` to manually check the content, but this appeared to be impossible, because there are thousands of elements.

Finally I just wrote this:

```
for item in sorted_list:
        file_content += str(item[0]) + ":" + str(item[1]) + "|"
```

And everything goes like clockwork. Why? Isn't this equivalent? Does anybody know the origin of this error?

Comment: Why not use try/except to catch the AttributeError in the original code and print out the culprit in the except clause?

Comment: Are you sure rewriting the loop in that way solved the problem? It seems like the sorting should raise the same problem. Maybe it's just random behaviour and some of your lists have those elements and others don't?

Comment: Could you please mention what kind of exact **`INPUT`** and **`OUTPUT`** along with the dictionary format that you looking out for???

Comment: You get the error when you fill the sorted_list, so of course you won't find the errorours element in the sorted_list. The errorous element probably exists in new_dict, not in sorted_list

Comment: Incidentally, building a string by repeated concatenation (`file_content += stuff`) is rather inefficient because Python strings are immutable, so a new `file_content` string has to be allocated every time through the loop. Either write the file line by line & let your OS's file buffering & caching handle the details, or use the `str.join` method.

Comment: in fact the error has been occurend in this line `sorted_list = sorted(new_dict[document_name], key=operator.itemgetter(1))` exactly when you tried to sort by the first item of tuples within `sorted_list`

Comment: can you please specify how you make the `new_dict`?

Comment: Uh, wouldn't `sorted(new_dict[document_name], key=operator.itemgetter(1))` return a list of keys? I would expect to see something more like `sorted(new_dict[document_name].items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1))` to get a key/value pair list.

Answer (score 0):

I think your data changed between your tests:

According to you, `'float' object has no attribute '__getitem` means:

```
There must be an item in sorted_list that cannot be unpaced in t1 and t2. Bizarrely I could ensure that each item in sorted_list is a tuple
```

I can't agree, if the error were from the for trying to affect a float int t1 and t2, the error would be `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.

The only other part in your code probably calling __getitem is itemgetter.

So your error seems to be:

```
$ cat miss.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import operator

document_name = 0
new_dict = {document_name: [.1]}

sorted_list = sorted(new_dict[document_name], key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for t1, t2 in sorted_list:
    print(str(t1) + ":" + str(t2) + "|")
```

test:

```
$ python miss.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "miss.py", line 8, in <module>
    sorted_list = sorted(new_dict[document_name], key=operator.itemgetter(1))
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

TL;DR: There were a float in an array (instead of a tuple in an array) in your new_dict before `new_dict[document_name].append((integer * other_integers[string][1], other_integers[string][0]))`

You probably tested it in a REPL and reused an already stuffed "new_dict" ?